# How to do npm scripts work vs direct commands?

Tags: npm, gulp, npm-scripts

I keep seeing this behavior, so I want to understand it. I install gulp and the gulp-cli (not globally). Typing the gulp command gives me `-bash: gulp: command not found`

I take the gulp command and drop it into an npm script and boom, it works. Can someone explain what's going on here?

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "gulp": "gulp", // This works!!
    "gulp-build": "gulp build" // As does this!!
  },
```

Comment: When installing locally (not globally) any executable file(s) are typically installed in the `node_modules/.bin/` directory which resides in your project directory. Try, **1)** `cd` to your project directory. **2)** Run `./node_modules/.bin/gulp` via your command line, and `./node_modules/.bin/gulp build`

Comment: The docs for [`npm run script`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script#description) states the following in the 5th paragraph:  _"In addition to the shell’s pre-existing `PATH`, `npm run` adds `node_modules/.bin` to the `PATH` provided to scripts..."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, that makes sense. I was looking for the relative path to gulp in the project couldn't find the right path. Indeed ./node_modules/.bin/gulp does work. And thank you RobC for quoting that telling line in the docs. Totally makes sense now!